# Objective C Adding content to a file

Tags: objective-c, file-io

I need to write several line to a file. How can I move to the next line so that the file content is not overwritten each time? I am using a for loop with the following code in it

> [anNSString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

The NSString. anNSString is reinitialized during each loop. SO i need to keep adding to the file path each during each loop.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just write it out all at once, rather than attempting to write it incrementally. `-[NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error]` will just overwrite the file each time - it does not append.

Here's an illustration:

```
NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString new];

// > anNSString is reinitialized during each loop. 
for ( expr ) {
    NSString * anNSString = ...;
    // > SO i need to keep adding to the file path each during each loop.
    [str appendString:anNSString];
}

NSError * outError(0);
BOOL success = [str writeToFile:path
                     atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          error:&outError];
[str release];
...
```

Comment: [`str appendString:anNSString];` will just keep adding on in the same line, correct? How do you specify where a line break should be written?

Comment: Got it, need to use `\r\n`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like the accepted answer is not correct since it didn't answer the original question. To solve the original question you should use an [NSOutputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it makes appending content to an existing file an easy task:

```
NSString *myString = @"Text to append!"; // don't forget to add linebreaks if needed (\r\n)
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:filePath append:YES];
[stream open];
NSData *strData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[stream write:(uint8_t *)[strData bytes] maxLength:[strData length]];
[stream close];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write to a new line each time, start with what is in @justin's answer, but add `[str appendString:@"\r\n"];` wherever you need new lines.

```
NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString new];

// > anNSString is reinitialized during each loop. 
for ( expr ) {
    NSString * anNSString = ...;
    // > SO i need to keep adding to the file path each during each loop.
    [str appendString:anNSString];
    [str appendString:@"\r\n"]; //****** THIS IS THE NEW LINE ******
}

NSError * outError(0);
BOOL success = [str writeToFile:path
                     atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          error:&outError];
[str release];
...
```

With this code, each `anNSString` will be on it's own line in the text file.